# Open port for docker container connected by VPN container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vpn

I want to run a docker container ([kmb32123/youtube-dl-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/kmb32123/youtube-dl-server)) through a VPN in order to access geo blocked content. I found a suitable VPN docker image ([ilteoood/docker-surfshark](https://hub.docker.com/r/ilteoood/docker-surfshark)). I am trying to combine these two images in a single `docker-compose.yml` file. However, I'm unable to publish the ports for `youtube-dl-server` because of conflicting options.

`conflicting options: port publishing and the container type network mode`

Is there an alternative way to have `youtube-dl-server` route traffic though the `docker-surfshark` container while still exposing port `8080` locally so I can access it?

```
version: "2"

services: 
  surfshark-uk:
    image: ilteoood/docker-surfshark
    container_name: surfshark
    environment: 
        - SURFSHARK_USER=foo
        - SURFSHARK_PASSWORD=bar
        - SURFSHARK_COUNTRY=uk
        - CONNECTION_TYPE=udp
    cap_add: 
        - NET_ADMIN
    devices:
        - /dev/net/tun
    restart: unless-stopped
  youtube-dl-uk:
    image: "kmb32123/youtube-dl-server"
    container_name: yt-download-uk
    network_mode: container:surfshark-uk
    depends_on:
      - surfshark-uk
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - /Users/greg/Desktop/ukvids:/youtube-dl
    restart: unless-stopped
```

```
greg@computer docker $ docker-compose up
WARNING: Found orphan containers (surfshark, 949001ea6405_yt-download-uk) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
Creating surfshark-uk ... done
Creating yt-download-uk ... error

ERROR: for yt-download-uk  Cannot create container for service youtube-dl-uk: conflicting options: port publishing and the container type network mode

ERROR: for youtube-dl-uk  Cannot create container for service youtube-dl-uk: conflicting options: port publishing and the container type network mode
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think publishing port in `surfshark-uk` container will do the same job as  `youtube-dl-uk` as its using network of `surfshark-uk`. so the port will be accessible on your host when try to hit

```
curl localhost:8080
yt-download-uk   | 172.26.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2020 02:03:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 720
```

So update docker-compose file and it should work.

```
  surfshark-uk:
    image: ilteoood/docker-surfshark
    container_name: surfshark
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

> The port forwarding takes place with the VPN container, not the one
> that reuses its IP stack.

[port publishing and the container type network mode](https://github.com/dperson/openvpn-client/issues/210#issuecomment-533752656)